# What is an inclusion in a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I was reading some [notes on Ring theory](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~bviray/teaching/RingHomomorphismsAndIsomorphisms.pdf) that I found online and it says this :

> If $R$ is any ring and $S ⊂ R$ is a subring, then the inclusion $i: S → R$ is a ring homomorphism.

I don't know what is meant by "inclusion $i: S → R$". Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: If you have a set $X$ and a subset $Y \subseteq X$ then there is a function $f : Y \to X$ sending $y \in Y$ to $y \in X$.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map) for inclusion map in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion of $S$ into $R$ is the function $i : S \to R$ given by $i(s) = s$, as $S$ is just a subset of $R$. The fact this is a ring homomorphism is clear. Why do we even want to talk about such a seemingly non-interesting map? Well if you have another ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to A$ then you can form the restriction of this map to $S$ just by precomposing with $i$, so we have $\phi \circ i:S \to A$.